# style not getting applied to component if I use the component's selector name

Tags: css, angular6

I have a component and I want to place it centrally within a grid. The selector of the component is `app-signup-component` and the rule I have applied is

```
app-signup-component{
  align-self:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

The it seems the rule is not getting applied. I am unable to figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

The top level component is `content-component`. Its `html` is

```
<div id="content-div"> <!--this is a flex -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Its `css` is

```
#content-div{
  display:flex; 
  height:75vh;
}

app-signup-component{
  align-self:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

The `app-signup-component` component gets added dynamically. It is a `form`. When I run the code, I see in the debugger window that css rules for `app-signup-component` are not applied (see attached pic)

[image]

If I manually add the rule in the browser then the form moves to the center (see below pic)

[image]

Comment: maybe you didn't compile?

Comment: The code is compiled as when I changed the height of the `content-div` to `100vh` then that was reflected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it worked but if I move the rule to `styles.css` which is the global `css` file applicable across all components then the code works. I suppose the issue might be that if a rule is added in component's local `css` then that component has to exist in the page when the page/component is loaded. In my case, `content component` has `router-outlet` and when `content component` some other component `homepage` at start up. When I click a `button`, `signup component` gets loaded. But because `signup component` was not present initially, the `css` rule doesn't gets applied to it when it is later loaded probably because the `browser` doesn't recalculate the `css` rules. I suppose my options are that I either redesign the architecture to keep `css` effects local or I add such rules in the global `styles.css`.

Comment: The problem could be due to a bug in Angular. Angular sometimes does not load the component specific css properly. Declaring css in global file always works!